# Query configuration table as a one time activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to query a DB table as a one time activity, so that the values can be used to drive a repeating pipeline activity.

Let's say I have a set of values that varies based on the environment(DEV/TEST/PROD). Instead of passing the values corresponding to the environment as parameters, can I configure these values in a DB table and read them the first time the Data Factory runs, so that a repeating Orchestrator task that runs every five minutes can fetch value obtained from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#example) activity for your case.

Specify your query in the Lookup activity to get the row you want to query for your environment value. You may also wants to check the "First row only" option for your case.
[image]

To access the value returned from DB, you can get the value from the output of the Lookup. It would be in the "firstRow" object of the output.
[image]

For the conditional/switch handling for your use case, put in `@activity('Lookup config table').output.firstRow.VALUE` for your `expression` in the Switch's dynamic content.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use lookup activity from azure data factory to query values from db and then use parameters to store them to use in next activities, please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-expression-language-functions)